# Python os listdir not working properly in Mac

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to list all folders of a directory using python in Mac os 10.8.2.

My code is as simple as this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf8
import os
print [name for name in os.listdir(os.path.abspath('.')) if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

When I run this script in a path where there are folders the outcome is:

```
[]
```

I try this same script in another computer (ubuntu) and it works perfectly, listing all the directories in the current path.

---

I have tried exactly the same in the python console in that path and it works, the outcome is:

```
['Final', 'Script_actualizacion', 'Z_L1']
```

What could be happening?

Comment: What is the resulting value of `os.path.abspath('.')`?

Comment: Try replacing `os.path.abspath('.')` with `'/Users'`, does it work?

Comment: @Tichodroma : The resulting value is: '/Users/jesusredondogarcia/Desktop/Abril/subidos a opendata/Autobuses/Autobuses v2 nueva contrata/Archivos/ttls' which is the path where the script is running, it's ok.

Comment: @RaphDG : No, it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe your python env is not set up correctly. Try using the /usr/bin/python directly. The first line of your script would become `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: You should also fix your [Encoding declaration](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations). Eg, `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok now this is working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf8
import os
path = os.path.abspath('.')
print [name for name in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,name))]
```

The problem happened because I was calling the python from a different location so it checked the dirs in the wrong path.

Comment: better to use `os.path.join(path,name)` instead of `path+'/'+name`.

Comment: @isedev yes, certainly better. Fixed.